# Picamera and streaming

Tags: python, stream, camera, video-streaming, raspberry-pi

I have this python script and this works fine:
http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.1/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream

I would like to connect to this with VLC or Windows Media player.
Anyone can help me to modify the script for this?

Answer (score 0):

First install the [python-vlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/PythonBinding) module using this command:

`pip install python-vlc`

Code:

```py
    import vlc
    playlist = ['Path to your file']
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer(playlist)
    player.play()
```

Hope this will help you. Cheers!!!